# difference between using the session via an HTTP request instance versus using the global session helper in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, dependency-injection

I could not find any information related two types of session access methods.
`$request->session()` from HTTP request instance and `session()` from session helper in Laravel 5.3 .
Is there any difference or which one to use when ?

How to send a get request to below controller method when using P.H.P unit

```
public function testMyMethod(Request $request){
$userExist = $request->session()->exists('user_id');
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container) is the core of the Laravel architecture. All services, components, and dependencies are registered there, and you can ask for any of them whenever you need it.

But Laravel provides more than one way to "ask for it". You have the global helper functions, you have facades, you have the "proper", "purer" injection of the component instance in the method signature. I think a big part of the philosophy of Laravel is a clean, easy, intuitive API. And in this case, it can be left up to your personal preference to define what  "clean and easy" is, and whatever matches your style will be, by definition, intuitive to you.

I know there have been heated debates in the PHP community as to which method is "best", facades have been controversial, traditional dependency injection OOP purists say the only right way may be injecting the object with the controller method signature...

In the end, any of this various methods just grab the object from the same service container bag. It makes no difference performance-wise (I bet two function calls of indirection won't hit your performance) or otherwise. So, use whatever suits your style better. I personally do the "proper" injection anyway if I'm in a typical controller, but maybe I use the global helper if it makes for a cleaner, more readable code in its context.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session;
use Facades\Illuminate\Contracts\Session\Session as SessionRealTimeFacade;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as RequestFacade;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session as SessionFacade;
use PHPUnit\Framework\Assert;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function sessionTest(Request $request, Session $session)
    {
        $options = [
            $request->session()->get('_token'),
            session()->get('_token'),
            session('_token'),
            $session->get('_token'),
            SessionFacade::get('_token'),
            SessionRealTimeFacade::get('_token'),
            app('session')->get('_token'),
        ];

        array_reduce(
            $options,
            function ($one, $other) {
                Assert::assertEquals($one, $other);
                return $other;
            },
            array_shift($options)
        );

        return 'All tests passed!';
    }    
}
```

And by the way, as you can see you have more than just 2 options :)

Of course, this doesn't apply to sessions only, the same goes for getting the request data, getting DB connection, and so much more.

(Also, I think you don't have the real-time facades in 5.3 yet)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. You said the difference between `request()->session()` and `session()` is something like 2 function calls, but isnt it more complicated then that? I mean they return two different objects in the end https://stackoverflow.com/a/43680476/2311074

Answer (score 6):

1. ### **Laravel Documentation**

According to the Laravel Docs - https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session - there is 'little practical difference between using the session via an HTTP request instance versus using the global session helper' and that both are testable.

`->assertSessionHas($key, $value = null);`

[image: Session - Laravel Docs]

2. ### **Laravel Up & Running - Matt Stauffer**

In his book (page 320-), Matt talks through the different ways available to access session information:

- **Using the `Session` facade**

  `session()->get('user_id');`
- **Using the `session()` method on any given Illuminate `Request` object**

  `Route::get('dashboard', function(Request $request) {
      $request->session()->get('user_id');
   });`
- **Inject an instance of `Illuminate\Session\Store`**

  `Route::get('dashboard', function(Illuminate\Session\Store $session) {
      return $session->get('user_id');
  });`
- **Using the global `session()` helper**

  `$value = session()->get('key);
  $value = session('key);`

His final comment is: ***If you're new to Laravel and not sure which to use, I'd recommend using the global helper***.

So, I wouldn't worry about the differences and just go with what 'feels right' for you.  If you have no preference either way, go with Matt Stauffer's recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, the way that you normally use the two options, there is no practical difference between `$request->session()` and `session()`. However, they do not technically return the same objects.

`session()` will return the `SessionManager`. `$request->session()` will return the session `Store`.

The `Store` is actually the object that contains the session data.

The `SessionManager` is the object that manages the available session `Store`s. Most applications will only ever use one session store (the default one).

The reason why they seem to act as the same object is that when you call a method on the `SessionManager` that doesn't exist, it forwards that method call to the default session `Store`.

So, in your example, you use the `exists()` method. This method does not exist on the `SessionManager`. So, if you were to call `session()->exists('user_id')`, it would forward that call down to the default session `Store`, and it would be equivalent to calling `$request->session()->exists('user_id')`.

One could argue that directly using `$request->session()` is more appropriate when attempting to access the session data, since that is what is returned, and doesn't require the additional forwarding function call. However, it is up to you to weigh the pros and cons to determine which method to use.

Answer (score 1):

$request->session() and session() both are same thing.

There are two primary ways of working with session data in Laravel: the global function in session() helper and via a $request instance.

you can use it like this

```
public function testMyMethod(Request $request){

    //$userExist = $request->session()->exists('user_id');
    $userExist = $request->session()->has('user_id');

}
```

Comment: I`ve used both ways. Want to know the difference (is there any performance impact , etc ...) since it`s easier for php unit when session helper used

Comment: Thanks pal, but I`m really looking out why they separated this

Comment: We can use session() function directly anywhere but $request object cant thats why this function introduced.

Comment: This does not answer the question. If you can always use in your Controllers the function `session()` why should you ever access it with `$request->session()`?

Answer (score -1):

Actually native PHP session is a ready solution versus a better implementation from Laravel and Symfony that had put more thought into it. Read the explanation at [Symfony Session configuration manual entry](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html) and you will understand i think. So there's a difference, but in the way it is thought and implemented. From the point of view from performance i think there isn't much. I will let you take your conclusions. Another entry that helps is at [PHP manual](http://php.net/session.customhandler)